# Cannot load pg_ext file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

When i try to run the server with rails s i get this issue:

```
/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require':

cannot load such file -- pg_ext (LoadError)
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about your environment. Do you use the pg gem in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling rubygems(2.0.3) and rails(4.0.0) solved the problem.

Comment: How do you reinstall rubygems?

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.17.1 was not working for me (same pg_ext load failure) but when I uninstalled it and installed the pre version of 0.18.0 that cleared up the problem.